# Confusion with Passing Obj-C objects into methods and retaining the changes to that object

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, pointers, reference

I'm writing a program and trying to learn more about threads, multiprocessing, and such.

My architecture is a Model/View/Controller type.

I have my own subclass of `NSImageView` (ThumbnailView) and I wanted to be clever and have it listen for a message to clear itself (so all the thumbnails just clear themselves without me having to loop through them).

The problem is my `ThumbnailView` is controlled by a `ThumbnailViewController` which is really the one listening for the message.  When it gets the message it spins off a new thread with a class object that is the command (`ClearThumbnailViewCommand`).  It passes as an argument a dictionary item containing the associated `ThumbnailView` object and a key.  Within the `ClearThumbnailViewCommand` I set the image of the `ThumbnailView` object to be some neutral image (like gray.jpg).

All this works fine, however, the Thumbnail object that changed is not the same Thumbnail object that went in.  So I figure I need to pass a pointer rather than the object.  I remember something about using `MyObject**` as opposed to `MyObject*` and passing via `&MyObject` but I can't seem to untangle the various combinations.  Not being able to reason it out I fell back to my, normally, foolproof system of trying random combinations of things but this time it's not helping.

It seems that even if I'm able to construct a class that passes a pointer (Not sure if I'm using these terms correctly), I'm not able to assign it correctly to the `NSDictionary`, which doesn't want an `id**` .

I'll try and include the basics below, if that helps at all.

---

```
ThumbnailVew : NSImageView {
    ThumbnailVewController  * _controller;
}

init  {
    _controller = [[ControllerClass alloc] initWithControlObject: &self];
}
```

---

```
ThumbnailVewController : ControllerClass {
    id  ** _controlObject;
}

initWithControlObject: (id**)object {
    _controlObject = object;
}
```

---

Then when messages are posted a `ThumbnailVewController` method is called which ultimately does this…
Which, of course will not let me pass in `&_controlObject`

when it is all re-written so that I can pass `_controlObject`, I don't get an error, however the `ThumbnailView` I change is only local to the method.

```
if([command isEqualToString:@"CLEAR_THUMBNAILS"]) {
    NSDictionary * dict;
    dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: &_controlObject, @"thumbnail", nil];

    [self newThreadWithCommand:[[[ClearThumbnailViewCommand alloc] initWithArgument:dict] autorelease]];
}
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: I'd recommend going through a tutorial regarding the C language and pointers before trying to untangle their use in Objective-C; otherwise it can be a bit confusing.

Comment: FYI `_controlObject` is declared as a triple pointer. `id` is already a pointer to an Objective-C object.

Comment: Although it sounds like one of your goals is to explore some Objective-C concepts, the solution seems more complex than the need requires.  One of the first clues is that the view (`ThumbnailView`) is holding a reference to it's controller.  Another solution to your specification of clearing multiple `ThumbnailView` objects without explicitly looping through them would be `NSNotification` wherein all of your instances would observe for a particular notification.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback.  I am indeed just trying to explore some various situations.  I understand I may be going a round about way to get at some things but it does help me understand the boundaries more clearly.

In case it might help anyone else, I found a solution to my particular issue.  As it turns out I was making the reference to the _controlObject in the init phase of the ThumbnailView.  The object created during that phase is different than the ThumbnailView object created when awakeFromNib is called.

when I move the _controlObject assignment to the awakeFromNib method all works as I expected.  (Of course I reset the code to not include any of the fancy ** and & declarations.

Again, thank you for helping me understand a bit more about this language.  I'm starting to like it quite a bit.